# Game window freezes whenever enter is pressed on textbox

Tags: python, pygame

I recently programmed a game in Pygame and added a text box (which I made using `pygame_gui`) which will send data directly to a MySQL database. But whenever I type something into the text box and press enter, the game window freezes.

This is the code of the program:

```py
run = True
while run:
    UI_REFRESH_RATE = clock.tick(60)/1000
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED and event.ui_object_id =="#main_text_entry":
            user_history = []
            username = showtext(event.text,user_history)
        manager.process_events(event)
    manager.update(UI_REFRESH_RATE)
    manager.draw_ui(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()

def showtext(text_to_show,user_history):
    user_history = []
    user_history += text_to_show
    print(user_history)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
    username = ""
    for i in user_history:
        username += i
    return username
```

Comment: Am I reading this correctly that you have a while loop which stops ONLY if the game is quit, and never advances otherwise? Did you mean to put something else inside this loop?

Comment: Yes the loop only stops when the game is quit. Should it stop for some other conditions too?

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is with this code, but when "enter" is hit (I suppose it's when `event.type == pygame_gui.UI_TEXT_ENTRY_FINISHED` occurs), you call `showtext` in which there is an infinite loop. The only way to exit this loop is by quitting. No other event is handled, and the only thing you ask your program to do is to render the display, thus appearing to be "frozen". You have an issue with the logic here.

Comment: My intention is to return the username variable and pass it onto the mysql database. I didn't realise I had created an infinite loop. I'm having trouble coming up with the logic. I want to get text input but also have it so the game can be quit at any instance

Comment: @cupbord first things first: you understand that the computer does things in the order you write (unless you tell it to do a different order), right? So when it gets to the line with `username = showtext(event.text, user_history)` it goes to the showtext function and does everything in the showtext function before it does anything else?